# wxpython animated gif as splash screen

Tags: python, animation, wxpython

I am struggling to get an animated gif file to play as a splash screen for my wxPython app.

I have successfully used a PNG file for the splash screen using a timeout option which works well but I wanted to use an animated GIF.

So I started using the wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl() which shows the GIF file but my app is visible behind the playing GIF file and I cannot get the GIF to stop and disappear.

```
ani = wx.animate.Animation("intro.gif")
ctrl = wx.animate.AnimationCtrl(self, -1, ani)
ctrl.SetUseWindowBackgroundColour()
ctrl.Play()
```

I then tried to use a wx.Sleep(5) and then ctrl.Stop() but this causes the GIF to not even show up.

I then tried to used the AdvancedSplashScreen which again works with a PNG but does not show an animated GIF file.

Has anyone successfully got one to work, if so how?

thanks

Comment: You probably need GIFAnimationCtrl() instead of AnimationCtrl()

Comment: not really an answer, but the source for AdvancedSplashScreen is available, perhaps you can subclass/use a modified version to do what you want.

Comment: Instead of just sleeping, try a busy loop with wx.Yield, or better yet a timer callback. And try setting the parent to None to avoid showing your app window.